# Static method changing value of the variable used as an argument

Tags: java, android, static-methods, android-livedata, utility

I have created a static method in a PredictionUtil class which is used to generate a new list from a smaller list. Instead of just being assigned to the new variable, the new updated list is also assigned to the smaller list. I am unable to understand this problem.

The utility class:

```
public class PredictionUtils {

    public static List<PeriodEntity> predictPeriods(List<PeriodEntity> past){
        List<PeriodEntity> updated = past;
        if(past == null){
            return null;
        }
        int pastsize = past.size();
        long currentcycledur = generateCurrentCycleDuration(past);
        long currentperioddur = generateCurrentPeriodDuration(past);
        long laststartdate = past.get(pastsize-1).getStartTimestamp();
        for(int i = 1;i <= 20;i++){
            updated.add(new PeriodEntity(laststartdate+(currentcycledur*i),laststartdate+(currentcycledur*i)+currentperioddur));
        }
        return updated;
    }

    public static long generateCurrentCycleDuration(List<PeriodEntity> past){
        long cycleduration = 0L;
        long diff;
        int pastsize = past.size();

        if(pastsize == 1){
            return cycleduration = 2419200000L;
        }

        if(pastsize < 5) {
            for (int i = 0; i < pastsize - 1; i++) {
                diff = past.get(i + 1).getStartTimestamp() - past.get(i).getStartTimestamp();
                cycleduration += diff;
            }
            return (cycleduration/(pastsize-1));
        }else{
            for (int i = pastsize-1;i >= pastsize-4;i--) {
                diff = past.get(i).getStartTimestamp() - past.get(i-1).getStartTimestamp();
                cycleduration += diff;
            }
            return (cycleduration/4);
        }
    }

    public static long generateCurrentPeriodDuration(List<PeriodEntity> past){
        long periodduration = 0L;
        long diff;
        int pastsize = past.size();

        if(pastsize < 4){
            for(int i = 0;i < pastsize;i++){
                diff = past.get(i).getEndTimestamp()-past.get(i).getStartTimestamp();
                periodduration += diff;
            }
            return (periodduration/pastsize);
        }else{
            for(int i = pastsize-1;i >= pastsize-4;i--){
                diff = past.get(i).getEndTimestamp()-past.get(i).getStartTimestamp();
                periodduration += diff;
            }
            return (periodduration/4);
        }
    }
}
```

Its use:

```
//Observable LiveData Elements
        calendarViewModel.getPastPeriods().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<PeriodEntity>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(final List<PeriodEntity> pastperiods) {

                nextPeriod = PredictionUtils.predictPeriods(pastperiods).get(pastperiods.size());

            }
        });
```

Value of the pastperiods and nextPeriod is same, why?

Comment: `updated = past`: They're the same list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new instance of List, you are referring to the input.

```
List<PeriodEntity> updated = past;
```

As a result, both `updated` and `past` lists are basically the same list. So whenever you are modifying `updated`, it also updates the `past`.

To avoid that, create a new `ArrayList` for `updated` and copy the existing data of `past` there.

```
List<PeriodEntity> updated = new ArrayList<>(past);
```

Comment: `List<PeriodEntity> updated = new ArrayList<>();
        updated = past;`

Comment: Tried this still but did not solve the problem, what else can I do?

Comment: `List<PeriodEntity> updated = new ArrayList<>(past);` worked! I am such a horrible programmer, just now realized that I have been copying all my Lists wrong!